# Junos how to execute a lot of repetitive commands?

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-junos

In my Juniper qfx Switch, I want to execute many commands such as bellow:

```
set vlans vlan77 vlan-id 77
set vlans vlan77 l3-interface irb.77
set vlans vlan78 vlan-id 78
set vlans vlan78 l3-interface irb.78
set vlans vlan79 vlan-id 79
set vlans vlan79 l3-interface irb.79
....
```

I couldn't to write one by one, because there are hundreds lines. I want to execute them in a simple and convenient way. who can help me with this?

Comment: One simple way is just to create a text script, and then paste it into your terminal program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

1. create a file with the set statements (probably using some script)
2. copy that file to your router
3. use `load set <filename>` to execute the set of statements

More information on loading configuration files can be found in [this Juniper document](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/junos-config-files-loading.html).